# Polarization after scattering on a surface?

Tags: optics, laser, scattering, polarization

I have two questions about polarization.

The first one is:
there is a wall of a building and a beam with linear polarization.
What will we see in backscattering? Which polarization? Circular (chaotic) or old one (linear) will be dominant?
How does it depend on the distance (for instance, 100 m)?

The second question is quite the same, but this time I'm interested in Mie scattering:
say we have rain, so what will happen to the polarization? After propagating through a certain distance, will polarization become more chaotic and therefore circular?

Polarization after scaterring on the surface? - ResearchGate. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Polarization_after_scaterring_on_the_surface [accessed Feb 12, 2017].